# Deduce type of a member of a template argument object

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, type-deduction

Having this function:

```
template <typename T>
T operator-(const T vector)
{}
```

I want to enforce that T has `x` and `y` members, and that they are arithmetic.
I was trying to do it via `std::declval<T>`:

```
template <typename T,
  typename = typename 
    std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<std::declval<T>.x>::value>::type,
  typename = typename 
    std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<std::declval<T>.y>::value>::type>
T operator-(const T vector)
{}
```

But all I get is, that the type cannot be deduced: *`error: insufficient contextual information to determine type`*. Can the type of a member of template parameter object be deduced at all?

Comment: The syntax `std::declval<T>.x` can be used only with an object, not with a type.

Comment: @RSahu: That's right. I didn't notice that. Thanks. Is it possible, by any means, to find out the type of a member of a passed object at compile time then?

Comment: I tried to use `std::is_arithmetic<typename T::x>::value`, it compiles, but it doesn't seem to do the work.

Comment: ofc `typename T::x` refers to a type, not an object. Still haven't solved this.

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<T>().x)`, or `decltype(T::x)`.

Comment: nice, it works @T.C. !

Comment: @T.C. The latter may unintentionally give false negatives for C++17 classes with operator dot overloaded. :o)

Comment: Well that's the first time I've seen that error. o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you don't actually want to enforce that they're arithmetic. You want that the crucial expressions in the function template's body are well-formed. In that case, go for something along the lines of

```
template <typename T>
auto operator-(const T& vector)
  -> decltype(void(x - vector.x), void(y - vector.y), vector)
{/* ... */}
```

If you'd rather stick to a correct version of your code, substituting `decltype(std::declval<T>().x)` or `decltype(T::x)` for `std::declval<T>.x` (ditto for `y`) is sufficient:

```
template <typename T,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(T::x)>{}>,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(T::x)>{}>>
T operator-(const T vector)
{}
```

Comment: I actually do want to ensure that they're arithemtic. I need to negate their values. It doesn't make sense if they are not arithemtic. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dundee: complex/rational numbers are not *arithmetic*, but negate them makes sense.

Comment: @Dundee The unary operator `-` can be overloaded.

Comment: @Jarod42: You're right. Fortunately, these do not fit into my use case.

Comment: @Columbo: Yes, I know. It has more to do with how I want the library to be used. Anyway, thanks for providing both options. You're amazing :)